# How to prevent InvalidOperationException with XmlDataSource in medium trust for the same domain

Tags: asp.net, medium-trust

I'm using an XmlDataSource to fetch an RSS feed **on the same domain**. Ever since my ISP moved to medium trust, that code is failing with a System.InvalidOperationException.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a forum post on my ISP's forums, it seems I have to ask them for my data source URL to get whitelisted. That's exactly what I did.